# calls to printf seem to overwrite array of strings

Tags: c, arrays, c-strings

Hello I am developing a program for the Raspberry in C (the in-progress project can be found [here](https://github.com/FrancescoBoi/RaspberryAlarm)).

I noted there are some errors in the `task1` function so I created an equivalent program in my Desktop (running Ubuntu) to find the error, where the `task1` was readapted as below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "stub.h"
#include "globals.h"
#include "utils.h"
#include <pthread.h>
#define INPIN 25
void takePic(char picname[24]);

//This thread reads the PIR sensor output
void task1()
{
    unsigned char val_read = 0;
    static unsigned char alarm_on = FALSE;
    static const unsigned int maxNumPics=10;
    static char folderPath[] = "/home/usr/Documents/alarmSys_rasp/alarm_new/pics/";
    char fileNameTodelete[73];
    fileNameTodelete[0] = '\0';
    strcat(fileNameTodelete, folderPath);
    //INITIALIZING
    pinMode(INPIN, INPUT);
    //create folder where to save pics
    createFolder(folderPath);

    char* names[24];
    char picname[24];
    int res = 0;
    picname[0] = '\0';
    static unsigned int numPicsInFolder;
    //delete if more than 10 files
    while((numPicsInFolder =  filesByName(names, folderPath))>maxNumPics)
    {

        fileNameTodelete[0] = '\0';
        strcat(fileNameTodelete, folderPath);
        strcat(fileNameTodelete, names[0]);
        printf("%s\n", fileNameTodelete);
        remove(fileNameTodelete);
    }

    static unsigned int nexEl;
    nexEl = numPicsInFolder % maxNumPics;
    printf("Entering while\n");
    while(1)
    {
        //static const unsigned int del = 300;

        val_read = digitalRead(INPIN);
        if (val_read && (!alarm_on)) //motion detected
        {
            printf("\nDetected movement\n");
            if (numPicsInFolder >= maxNumPics)
            {
                printf("\nMax num pics\n");
                fileNameTodelete[0] = '\0';
                strcat(fileNameTodelete, folderPath);
                strcat(fileNameTodelete, names[nexEl]);
                printFiles(names, numPicsInFolder);
                printf("File to be deleted %d: %s, ", nexEl, names[nexEl]);
                //printf("%s\n", fileNameTodelete);

                if ((res = remove(fileNameTodelete))!=0)
                {
                    printf("Error deleting file: %d\n", res);
                }

            }
            else
            {
                printf("\nNot reached max num pics\n");
                numPicsInFolder++;
            }
            //update buffer
            takePic(picname);
            printf("value returned by takePic: %s\n", picname);
            //names[nexEl] = picname;
            strcpy(names[nexEl], picname); //ERROR HERE
            printFiles(names, numPicsInFolder);

            printf("curr element %d: %s\n",nexEl, names[nexEl]);

            nexEl++;
            nexEl %= maxNumPics;
            printf("\nDetected movement: alarm tripped\n\n");
            alarm_on = TRUE;
            /*Give some time before another pic*/
        }
        else if (alarm_on && !val_read)
        {
            alarm_on = FALSE;
            printf("\nAlarm backed off\n\n");
        }
    }

}


void takePic(char picname[24])
{
    /*Build string to take picture*/
    int err;
    //finalcmd is very long
    char finalcmd[150];
    finalcmd[0] = '\0';
    getDateStr(picname);

    char cmd1[] = "touch /home/usr/Documents/alarmSys_rasp/alarm_new/pics/";
    char cmdlast[] = "";


    strcat(finalcmd, cmd1);
    strcat(picname, ".jpg");
    strcat(finalcmd, picname);
    strcat(finalcmd, cmdlast);
    system(finalcmd);

    if ((err=remove("/var/www/html/*.jpg"))!=0)
    {
        printf("Error deleting /var/www/html/*.jpg, maybe not existing\n" );
    }
    //system(finalcmd_ln);
    //pthread_mutex_lock(&g_new_pic_m);
    g_new_pic_flag = TRUE;
    printf("\nPicture taken\n\n");

}
```

**DESCRIPTION**

The main function calls the `task1` function defined in the file `task1.c`. The function creates a file in the folder `./pics/` every time the condition `(val_read && (!alarm_on))` is verified (in the simulation this condition is satisfied every 2 loops). The function allows only 10 files in the folder. If there are already 10, it deletes the oldest one and creates the new file by calling the function `takePic`.

The name of files are stored in a array of strings `char* names[24];` and the variable `nexEl` points to the element of this array having the name of the oldest file so that it is replaced with the name of the new file just created.

**PROBLEM**

The problem is the following: the array `char* names[24]` is correctly populated at the first iteration but already in the second iteration some elements are overwritten. The problem arises when the folder has the maximum number of files (10) maybe on the update of the array.
It seems the calls to `printf` overwrite some of its elements so that for example one of them contains the string `"Error deleting /var/www/html/*.jpg, maybe not existing\n"` printed inside the funtion `takePic`.

What am I missing or doing wrong with the management of arrays of strings?

**UTILITIES FUNCTIONS**

To be complete here are shortly described and reported other functions used in the program.
The function `getDateStr` builds a string representing the current date in the format `yyyy_mm_dd_hh_mm_ss`.

The function `filesByName` builds an array of strings where each string is the name of a file in the folder `./` ordered from the last file created  to the newest.

The function `printFiles` prints the previous array.

```
void getDateStr(char str[20])
{
    char year[5], common[3];

    time_t t = time(NULL);
    struct tm tm = *localtime(&t);
    str[0]='\0';
    sprintf(year, "%04d", tm.tm_year+1900);
    strcat(str, year);
    sprintf(common, "_%02d", tm.tm_mon + 1);

    strcat(str, common);

    sprintf(common, "_%02d", tm.tm_mday);
    strcat(str, common);

    sprintf(common, "_%02d", tm.tm_hour);
    strcat(str, common);

    sprintf(common, "_%02d", tm.tm_min);
    strcat(str, common);

    sprintf(common, "_%02d", tm.tm_sec);
    strcat(str, common);
    //printf("%s\n", str);

}

unsigned int countFiles(char* dir)
{
    unsigned int file_count = 0;
    DIR * dirp;
    struct dirent * entry;
    dirp = opendir(dir); /* There should be error handling after this */
    while ((entry = readdir(dirp)) != NULL) {
        if (entry->d_type == DT_REG) { /* If the entry is a regular file */
             file_count++;

        }
    }
    return file_count;

}

void printFiles(char* names[24], unsigned int file_count)
{
    for (int i=0; i<file_count; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", names[i]);
    }
}

unsigned int filesByName(char* names[24], char* dir)
{
    unsigned int file_count = 0;
    DIR * dirp;
    struct dirent * entry;
    dirp = opendir(dir); /* There should be error handling after this */

    while ((entry = readdir(dirp)) != NULL) {
        if (entry->d_type == DT_REG) { /* If the entry is a regular file */
             //strncpy(names[file_count], entry->d_name,20);
            //names[file_count] = malloc(24*sizeof(char));
            names[file_count] = entry->d_name;
             file_count++;
        }
    }
    closedir(dirp);
    char temp[24];
    if (file_count>0)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<file_count-1; i++)
        {
            for (int j=i; j<file_count; j++)
            {
                if (strcmp(names[i], names[j])>0)
                {
                    strncpy(temp, names[i],24);
                    strncpy(names[i], names[j],24);
                    strncpy(names[j], temp, 24);
                    }
            }
        }
    }
    return file_count;
}
```

For the simulation I created also the following function (`digitalRead` is actually a function of the `wiringPi` C library for the Raspberry):

```
int digitalRead(int INPIN)
{
    static int res = 0;
    res = !res;
    return res;
}
```

Comment: `What am I missing or doing wrong with the management of arrays of strings?`You use `strcat()` too often. Take a look at `sprintf()`or, even better: `snprintf()` And: your character buffers seem too small.

Comment: `names[file_count] = entry->d_name;` copies the pointer `entry->d_name` to `names[file_count]`.  In the next iteration, with `file_count` 1 greater,  `names[file_count] = entry->d_name;` copies the same pointer to the next `names[file_count]`.  Code needs to save the contents of the _string_ at `entry->d_name`.  [@Craig Estey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49477172/2410359) discusses some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

In `task1`, you have `char *names[24]`. This is an array of `char` pointers.

In `filesByName`, you do

`names[file_count] = entry->d_name;`

but should be doing

`names[file_count] = strdup(entry->d_name);`

because you can't guarantee that `d_name` persists or is unique after the function returns or even within the loop. You were already close with the commented out `malloc` call.

Because you call `filesByName` [possibly] multiple times, it needs to check for `names[file_count]` being non-null so it can do a `free` on it [to free the old/stale value from a previous invocation] before doing the `strdup` to prevent a memory leak.

Likewise, in `task1`,

```
strcpy(names[nexEl], picname); //ERROR HERE
```

will have similar problems and should be replaced with:

```
if (names[nexEl] != NULL)
    free(names[nexEl]);
names[nexEl] = strdup(picname);
```

There may be other places that need similar adjustments. And, note that in `task1`, `names` should be pre-inited will `NULL`

---

Another way to solve this is to change the definition of `names` [everywhere] from:

```
char *names[24];
```

to:

```
char names[24][256];
```

This avoids some of the `malloc`/`free` actions.

Comment: From firrst runs it seems free(names[nexEl]); is making the program crash

Comment: Rather than the magic number 256, consider using the maximum filename length possible from `entry->d_name`.  E.g.  `sizeof entry->d_name` when it is an array or maybe [`NAME_MAX + 1`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/dirent.h.html).

Comment: @Craig Estey Thank for your help...the problem was that names being declared as `char* names[24]`, its elements need to be allocated the proper space so doing for example

`if (names[i]==NULL) malloc(names[i], sizeof(char)*24)`

or declaring it as char `names[10][24]` and changing the code properly

Answer (score 1):

`getDateStr()` uses a `char` buffer that is always too small.  Perhaps other problems exists too.

```
void getDateStr(char str[20]) {
  char year[5], common[3];
  ....
  sprintf(common, "_%02d", tm.tm_mon + 1);  // BAD, common[] needs at least 4
```

Alternative with more error checking

```
char *getDateStr(char *str, size_t sz) {
  if (str == NULL || sz < 1) {
    return NULL;
  }
  str[0] = '\0';

  time_t t = time(NULL);
  struct tm *tm_ptr = localtime(&t);
  if (tm_ptr == NULL) {
    return NULL;
  }    
  struct tm tm = *tm_ptr;

  int cnt = snprintf(year, sz, "%04d_%02d_%02d_%02d_%02d_%02d", 
      tm.tm_year+1900, tm.tm_mon + 1, tm.tm_mday,
      tm.tm_hour, tm.tm_min, tm.tm_sec);
  if (cnt < 0 || cnt >= sz) {
    return NULL;
  }
  return str;
}
```

Comment: You mean the common buffer or the fact the function has a 20 buffer input and I feed it with a 24 buffer?

Comment: @FrancescoBoi `sprintf(common, "_%02d", tm.tm_mon + 1);` attempts to write at least 4 characters to `char common[3];`.  Example: `'_'`, `'0'`, `'3'`, `'\0'` for today's time-stamp, This is buffer overflow and leads to _undefined behavior_.  `char common[3]` is _too small_.

Comment: thats true...its an improvement but maybe not th main issue